# How to apply constraints to optimisation in jax.scipy.optimize.minimize

Tags: jax

I am trying to minimize the function so that the value of x that minimizes it remains between 0 and 1. One possible walk around is using sigmoid transformation. Is there any other solution associated with jax in such cases? Here is a minimal example:

```
import jax
from jax.scipy.optimize import minimize
import jax.numpy as jnp
rng = jax.random.PRNGKey(0)

def gen_num(shape):
  return jax.random.uniform(rng,shape)

shape = (10,) 
mu = gen_num(shape)*2+3
log_sigma = gen_num(shape)*2
c = gen_num(shape)
x1 = gen_num((10,10))*4 +5

def kl_loss(x1, mu, log_sigma, c):
    return -(log_sigma* c[:, jnp.newaxis]).mean() + jnp.log(jnp.std(x1))

kl_value = lambda x: kl_loss(x1, mu, log_sigma, x)
res = minimize(kl_value, c, method='BFGS', tol=1e-5)
ans = res.x
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jax.scipy.optimize.minimize` is quite limited. The JAX team recommends [`jaxopt`](https://jaxopt.github.io/) instead; it has information on constrained optimization [here](https://jaxopt.github.io/stable/constrained.html).

If you can edit your question here to expand your example snippet into a full [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I could add an example of how to adapt your code for use with `jaxopt`.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the post by including a minimal reproducible example. Could you please now show how to adapt it to jaxopt? Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 3):

The only supported method in Jax is "BFGS". As you might see it doens't support hard constraint. However passing the constraint in the objective function can do the trick. For instance you can artificially increase the gradient outside [0, 1]:

```py
def objective_function(x: jnp.array, mu: float, log_sigma: float, x1: jnp.array):
  """Objective function."""
  kl_value = kl_loss(x1, mu, log_sigma, x)
  constraint = 10 * (1 - jnp.where(0 <= x <= 1)) * (x - 0.5)**2
  return k1_value + constraint

res = minimize(kl_value, c, args=(mu, log_sigma, x1), method='BFGS', tol=1e-5, )
```

In this case the gradient outside the domain is proportional to `10*(x-0.5)` which may be sufficient to maintain the value in the domain while having no impact inside the domain.

Finally you can try to fit the factor "10" to have a stable training and an efficient constraint.

This trick worked for me when I tried to implement a SVM in jax with `jax.scipy.optimize.minimize`.